# Setting or not a trigger on image loaded depending on a boolean view model property

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, visual-studio-2019, .net-4.5

I have an WPF image which has a trigger on Load. How can I make it conditional based on a boolean view model property. I mean, if this property is set to true, then I set the trigger. Otherwise, Loaded trigger should not be set on the image.

```
<Image Source="{DynamicResource ico_spinnerDrawingImage}" Width="100">
    <Image.Triggers>
        <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="Loaded">
            <BeginStoryboard>
                <Storyboard>
                    <DoubleAnimation From="0" To="360" Duration="0:0:1"
                                        Storyboard.TargetProperty="Source.Drawing.Transform.Angle"
                                        RepeatBehavior="Forever"/>
                </Storyboard>
            </BeginStoryboard>
        </EventTrigger>
    </Image.Triggers>
</Image>
```

I want to do this by only using XAML syntax, not code behind.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could try to refer to the following code.

```
     <Window.DataContext>
        <local:ViewModel />
    </Window.DataContext>
<TextBox x:Name="tb" Text="{Binding ShouldAnimate,Mode=TwoWay,UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}" />
        <Image Margin="300,200" Width="200" Height="250" Source="C:\Users\Admin\source\repos\1122\TriggerDemo\45.jpg"  Tag="{Binding ShouldAnimate}" RenderTransformOrigin="0.5,0.5">
            <Image.LayoutTransform>
                <RotateTransform Angle="0"/>
            </Image.LayoutTransform>
            <Image.Style>
                <Style TargetType="Image">
                    <Style.Triggers>
                        <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=tb,Path=Text, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"   Value="True">
                            <DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                                <BeginStoryboard>
                                    <Storyboard>
                                        <DoubleAnimation Duration="0:0:1" From='0'
                                                 To="145"  RepeatBehavior="Forever"
                                                 Storyboard.TargetProperty="(LayoutTransform).(RotateTransform.Angle)"/>

                                    </Storyboard>
                                </BeginStoryboard>
                            </DataTrigger.EnterActions>
                        </DataTrigger>
                      
                    </Style.Triggers>
                </Style>
            </Image.Style>
        </Image>
```

Codebehind:

```
public class ViewModel : INotifyPropertyChanged
    {
       
        
        private string _shouldAnimate ;
        public string ShouldAnimate
        {
            get { return _shouldAnimate; }
            set
            {
                _shouldAnimate = value;
                OnPropertyChanged("ShouldAnimate");
            }
        }
        public ViewModel()
        {
            ShouldAnimate = "False";
        }
       
        public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
        internal void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propName = "")
        {
            PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propName));
        }
    }
```

The result:
[image]